# PHP + TCPDF lib

Tags: php, pdf, foreach, row, tcpdf

My basic objective is sending inserted data by user to php file and then list all table rows  to PDF using PHP and TCPDF library (number of rows is inexplicit).

FORM (insert-data.php):

```
<form action="pdf/generate-pdf.php" method="get">
<table name="materialTable">
<tr>
<td><textarea rows="2" name="materialItemName[]"></textarea></td>
<td><input type="text" name="materialUnitPrice[]" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="materialItemQuantity[]" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="materialItemCoeff[]" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="materialItemPriceNoVat[]" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="materialItemVat[]" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="materialItemPriceInVat[]" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

GETTING VARS (pdf/generate-pdf.php)

```
$matn = $_GET['materialItemName'];
$matup = $_GET['materialUnitPrice'];
$matq = $_GET['materialItemQuantity'];
$matut = $_GET['materialUnitType'];
$matic = $_GET['materialItemCoeff'];
$matipnv = $_GET['materialItemPriceNoVat'];
$mativ = $_GET['materialItemVat'];
$matipiv = $_GET['materialPriceInVat'];

foreach( $matn as $key => $matn ) {
  echo "Title ".$matn.
    "Unit Price ".$matup[$key].
        "Quantity ".$matq[$key].
        "Unit ".$matut[$key].
        "Coefficient ".$matic[$key].
        "Total ".$matipnv[$key].
        "Vat ".$mativ[$key].
        "Total + Vat ".$matipiv[$key].
    "<br />"; }
```

WHAT´S MY PROBLEM? I need to put data into below.
Any ideas? Thank you for any help or advice

```
$material_listing_data = 'HERE';
$pdf->writeHTML($material_listing_data, true, false, true, false, '');
```

Comment: Assuming you started the TCPDF class properly then my immediate sighting is that you are echoing the data instead of appending to the `$material_listing_data` variable.

Comment: The PDF is perfect, everything besides this is functional. What is your advice? Change `$matn` to `material_listing_data`? If so, I've just try it, but it didn't help. You know, Im a beginner and try to fix this problem long time. I don't get it

Comment: Are you a beginner in PHP or TCPDF?

Comment: I´m a beginner in general but I've just resolve the problem

`foreach( $matn as $key => $matn ) {
  $material_listing_data .= "Nazev ".$matn.
                "Jednotkova cena ".$matup[$key].
        "Mnozstvi ".$matq[$key].
        "Jednotka ".$matut[$key].
        "Koeficient ".$matic[$key].
        "Celkem bez DPH ".$matipnv[$key].
        "DPH sazba ".$mativ[$key].
        "Celkem s DPH ".$matipiv[$key].
                "<br /><br />"; }
$pdf->writeHTML($material_listing_data, true, false, true, false, '');`

Thanks for your response

Comment: I am glad you have it working and yes that was my advice from the first comment.

Comment: :) I'm so sorry, my English didn't get it before :) I really appreciate it, how can I requite?

Comment: Well, thank you again, for efforts to help at minimum

Comment: You are welcome. If language is an issue then I would recommend writing it in your questions because this is an English website primarily so it will help people to make it easier for you to understand their comments and answers. You did format your code very nicely so it was easy for me to see the problem :) Good luck!